# Writing to PCIe registers at offsets > 0x1000

Tags: linux, pci-express, register

I'm on Ubuntu 22. I have a PCIe device (Intel H310 LPC), and I'd like to write to a particular configuration register (GEN_PMCON_A).

According to [the datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/300-series-chipset-pch-datasheet-vol-2.pdf) (p. 174), the GEN_PMCON_A register is at offset 0x1020:

> [image]

However, I was always under the impression that PCIe only specified 4096 bytes (0x1000) of configuration space, and so 0x1020 is past the end of that.

And, indeed, `setpci` fails to access the register, reporting that the address is out of range (and I confirmed in the `setpci` source code that [it maxes out at 0x1000](https://github.com/pciutils/pciutils/blob/548a6e3b9a3c5814db20acf5bcd3d894ce41b019/setpci.c#L743)):

```
# setpci -s 00:1f.0 0x1020.l
setpci: Register number 1020 out of range.
```

How can I read/write this register?

Comment: What about this Q/A?  https://superuser.com/questions/1087635/how-are-pci-devices-accessed

Comment: @A.B Thanks but that doesn't really help :) I know the mechanics of the mapping, I just can't find a way to access beyond the standard 4096 bytes (I've already tried writing a test program to map the devices config/resource address space but it seg faults when accessing past the 4096th byte; I also tried hacking `setpci` to remove the max address check but it still fails to read past 4096). I don't understand how this device has registers with offsets > 4096 and how it expects me to access them.

Comment: Those registers are memory mapped registers accessed based on offsets from the base address PWRMBASE which you can find in table 5-1 on page 140 - yes, I used many of the words from the picture you posted to describe what those registers are

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, how can I access them? Their addresses are all above 0x1000. They appear to be outside of the standard configuration space.

Comment: which is irrelevant as they are not the registers setpci is for (as far as I am aware)

Comment: @JaromandaX I believe they are. All of the other registers in those tables below 0x1000 are accessible with `setpci`.

Comment: those tables? 5.3 shows ONLY addresses above 0x1000 ... so, which ones do you claim work? the ones in table 5.1 (configuration)? or 5.2 (I/O based registers)? and those two sets of registers overlap (if you believe they refer to the same method of use) - setpci is used for the config registers in table 5.1 ... ONLY

Comment: @JaromandaX What do I use for these registers?

Comment: search for *linux access mmio*

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok; I used `setpci` (after confirming it retrieved expected values for config space registers) to get `PWRMBASE` and see that it is 0 (so no extra offset). I then used `memtool md -s /dev/mem 0x1020` to read address 0x1020 from /dev/mem but the entire area is read back as all 0's, which is unexpected (since those registers in that area should have a few non-zero default values). So either /dev/mem is not the correct device to read or I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: Also there are no files in */sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/* that are over 4096 bytes (I tried looking for stuff there to read too).

Comment: what about `PWRMBASE HIGH`?

Comment: It's also zero.

Comment: I wonder if it's something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/76314808/616460, but that answer doesn't have any more info, unfortunately.